# How to use WebView.addJavascriptInterface to bind java class with javascript function format as "A.B.func()"

Tags: android, webview

I want to support some self-define JavaScript interface with format "A.B.func()" on my app's WebView activity.

Here is a sample

The web page's html&js code is such as:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write("B.func1() return " + A.B.func());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my java code is such as:

```
public class MyDemo extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new AClass(), "A");
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mydemo.html");
    }

    final class AClass {
        final class BClass {
            BClass() {}
            int func() { return 1; }
        }

        public BClass B = new BClass();

        AClass() {}
    }
}
```

But when I run my app on simulator it can't run on right way. And the LogCat send warning to me such as:
  `TypeError : Result of expression 'A.B' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/mydemo.html`

So my question is:
1. if I want to bind javascript interface format as "A.B.func()" to my java class, how can I do it?
2. if I want to get javascript class's property directly, not by function calling, how can I do it?
     a javascript sample to show Q2
     use "var prop = A.property"
     not use "var prop = A.getProperty()"

Expect your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can. You could just add methods in A, like b_doSomething(){B.doSomething()} to "forward" your calls, and call those from javascript.

As for accessing properties, I'm not sure it's possible, the Javascript Interface is made for calling methods (pretty much like a normal Java Interface, I guess).

Answer (score 3):

Eclispe show message in LogCat "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toast'". But in phone it works successfully...

```
<script>
    function doHemant() {
       jse.doThis();
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Toast" onClick="doHemant();" /> <br />

wv.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptExtensions(), "jse");

class JavaScriptExtensions 
{ 
    public void doThis() 
    {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wata Toast...", TOAST_LONG).show();
    }
}
```